# Непонятные символы в консоли Arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

[image: Непонятные символы при работе с ардуино нано]

При работе с ардуино нано(конечно китайской) и библиотекой rf24 после определенного время нормальной работы начинает выводиться странный текст с непонятными символами.Я не знаю что с этим делать,поэтому обращаюсь к вам.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include "nRF24L01.h"
#include "RF24.h"

#include <Servo.h>
Servo serv;

RF24 radio(9, 10);  // инициализировать модуль на пинах 9 и 10 Для Уно
//RF24 radio(9,53); // Для Меги
byte data[2];

byte address[][6] = {"1Node", "2Node", "3Node", "4Node", "5Node", "6Node"}; //возможные номера труб

void setup() {
  data[0]=90;

  serv.attach(2);
  Serial.begin(9600);         // открываем порт для связи с ПК
  radio.begin();              // активировать модуль
  radio.setAutoAck(1);        // режим подтверждения приёма, 1 вкл 0 выкл
  radio.setRetries(0, 15);    // (время между попыткой достучаться, число попыток)
  radio.enableAckPayload();   // разрешить отсылку данных в ответ на входящий сигнал
  radio.setPayloadSize(32);   // размер пакета, в байтах

  radio.openReadingPipe(1, address[0]);   // хотим слушать трубу 0
  radio.setChannel(0x60);     // выбираем канал (в котором нет шумов!)

  radio.setPALevel (RF24_PA_MAX);   // уровень мощности передатчика. На выбор RF24_PA_MIN, RF24_PA_LOW, RF24_PA_HIGH, RF24_PA_MAX
  radio.setDataRate (RF24_250KBPS); // скорость обмена. На выбор RF24_2MBPS, RF24_1MBPS, RF24_250KBPS
  //должна быть одинакова на приёмнике и передатчике!
  //при самой низкой скорости имеем самую высокую чувствительность и дальность!!

  radio.powerUp();        // начать работу
  radio.startListening(); // начинаем слушать эфир, мы приёмный модуль
}


void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  byte pipeNo;
  while (radio.available(&pipeNo)) {        // слушаем эфир со всех труб
    radio.read(&data, sizeof(data));  // чиатем входящий сигнал
       

  }
  serv.write(data[0]);
  //Serial.println(data[1]);

}
```